# C# Adding Whitespace around a specific character for spacing in file names

Tags: c#, regex, string

I'm building a program which processes documents based on their file path and file name.
My current solution is based on file names containing 3 strings each separated by a space, dash and another space so that a valid name would be: "STRING1 - STRING2 - STRING3.pdf".
My program reads these values by using IndexOf().

```
string1.Substring(fileName.IndexOf("-") - 1)
string3.Substring(fileName.LastIndexOf("-") + 2)
```

The problem is that this breaks when the file names don't contain whitespaces, therefore breaking everything. So I opted to use Regex instead but how would I add a condition, so it doesn't add spaces to a name which already contains them.

Example,

```
String fileName[1] = "Test123 - Dog - Page 1.pdf"
String fileName[2] = "Test123-Dog-Page1.pdf"
Regex.Replace(fileName[1], "-", " - ");
Regex.Replace(fileNameB[2], "-", " - ");
```

Output:

```
fileName[1] = Test123  -  Dog  -  Page 1.pdf
fileName[2] = Test123 - Dog - Page 1.pdf
```

fileName[1] was originally valid, now it's invalid.
fileName[2] was originally invalid, now it's valid.
I need both to be valid via an if condition.

Ps. Apologies if anything is unclear, I'm new to posting on Stack

Comment: Either `(?<=\S)-(?=\S)`, or `\s*-\s*` to replace with `" - "`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need regex, in case pure string methods are more readable for you:

```
string FixFileName(string fn)
{
    string fnwe = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fn);
    return string.Join(" - ", fnwe.Split('-').Select(token => token.Trim()))
        + System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fn);
}
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/alv6sB

Comment: Nice code! A small point to notice for OP is that this also allows `a - b - c - d.pdf` to be allowed, so a verification is needed either before or after fixing.